# DotNetNuke 6 Child site can't have a site alias which already exists even though it doesn't

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-6, dotnetnuke-settings

I have a DNN6 Website which has a child site. The child sites Site alias is currently of the form 111.111.111.111/child-site-name (obviously not its real name).

I want to change this to www.mainsite.com/child-site-name. So I go to the site settings like a normal person would do and try to add a new site alias. No dice. The error is that a site with that alias already exists, even though it doesn't.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here?

My thought is that a previous child site used that alias, and upon deletion, did not free up the alias for later use. I have no idea where that information would be recorded though.

Thanks in advance everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can login as host and go to Host>SQL, then paste the following script:

```
SELECT * FROM {databaseOwner}[{objectQualifier}PortalAlias]
```

and run without ticking the "Run as script" option.

This will show you all portal aliases you have in your database.

Then if you find it there, you could eventually backup your database and try to delete it from there.

Comment: Sadly, no luck. The offending entries are not in the PortalAlias table.

Comment: I'm marking this as the right answer because you were on the right track. A colleague just added a new record directly into the PortalAlias table and this resolved the issue. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

For me this issue was resolved differently.  I hope it can help somone else.

When you add an alias like you mentioned  www.mysite.com/aliassite dnn will create a folder in the root of the dnn install with the name aliassite that redirects to your portal.  you have to remove the alias record and the named folder in your dnn root.  Then you can re add an alias that was already used.